# I have been facing problem with "Unresolved reference: contains" in kotlin android studio with most of the functions

Tags: function, kotlin, contains, unresolved-external

Unresolved reference: contains
while developing the android app I used the function "contains" in kotlin and keep getting the error unresolved reference there are many other functions also which show the same error I tried many ways to solve it but yet no progress code still runs.

I was trying to find the arithmetic operator in the string with contains keyword which is working fine is finds the operator but that error is still their unresolved reference: contains there are many other functions which have same problem they work fine but show the problem unresolved reference"xyz_function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVxX3.png)

Comment: Please provide some code example and the error, so someone can help you.

Comment: Attached the image in the description.

Comment: Try going to File->Invalidate Caches and Restart. After it restarts, Clean your project.

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image. Post it in in a code block. Nobody wants to open images of your code.